# How can i null the ViewBag property when i comming back to index view?

Tags: c#

I am showing the message in the bootstrap alert box. When i click the google chrome page back aero for comming back to the index view the alert box show  but i close that when alert box first time show in index view. How can i resolve this issue.
I show the message of api responce in bootstrap alert box from server side  i store the message in tempdata the i copy tempdata to viewbag and then i null the tempdata in my index action

here my action

Here my index view...

```
<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible text-center" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    @ViewBag.Message
</div>
```

Comment: store a bool flag, on session, or global etc. on first set of viewbag set it true. net time it will show true means you already have filled. then if that flag is true then set your viewbag to null.

Comment: let me know if this is a solution fro you then i will tell the code for it.

Comment: not work for me  issue is that when click to the goole chrome back aero option from another page to come back to the index view my alert box will be show already close this

Comment: GOt it. its a frontend work. you need to store a cookie and flag true at first time and each time page reload or come back just check that cookie value is true. GOt that?

Comment: show me example plxz

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {

    var flag = localStorage.getItem("myPopup");

    if(flag == "true"){ //means popup was already shown:

        //hide popup if its second time.
        $("#popDiv").hide();
    }
    else{ //means popup is show for first time:

        //set flag:
        localStorage.setItem("myPopup", "true");
    }
 });
```

Comment: rename your id names and variables properly.

Comment: thanks  your method is working  but this method my problem not resolve

Comment: it must help. what the issue tell me?

Comment: when i post the request responce msg will come i show this msg in alert box in my index in same controller msg i close that after read the alert box

Comment: when do other activity like go to other page and back to index  then again alert box show

Comment: it does not null view bag property when i come again in index view

Comment: ok. where is the alert box code written. is it on master page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199000/discussion-between-muhammad-safyan-and-ajay-kumar).